# chessboard: How to add or inherit styles?

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

Is it possible to add styles? 
I add for example a style 's1' on a style 's2':

```
\storechessboardstyle{s1}{
movenr={1},  
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
}

\storechessboardstyle{s2}{
style=s1,% <----------------   no effect! 
movenr={2}, 
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
}
```

But this does not work. 
What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak, pgfplots}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}
\setchessboard{pgfstyle=straightmove, color=red}

\begin{document}
\section{Works}
\newchessgame[setwhite={Ba8}]
\hidemoves{1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}

\storechessboardstyle{s}{
movenr={1},  
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
movenr={2}, 
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
}
\chessboard[tinyboard, style=s]
%======================================

\section{Works not}
\newchessgame[setwhite={Ba8}
]
\hidemoves{1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}

\storechessboardstyle{s1}{
movenr={1},  
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
}

\storechessboardstyle{s2}{
style=s1,% <----------------   no effect! 
movenr={2}, 
markmove=\xskakget{movefrom}-\xskakget{moveto},
}

\subsection{Style s1  - ok}
%\setchessboard{style=s1}
\chessboard[tinyboard,   style=s1]

\subsection{Style s2 - not ok (should include s1)}
%\setchessboard{style=s2}
\chessboard[tinyboard, style=s2] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't. It was already difficult enough to get styles working with xkeyval. I would have to rewrite the key handling. But this will certainly not happen in the next months.

Comment: Oh, what a pitty.  I fear, I will never solve my main-problem.